# Which JS Script Engine will be chosen by Java?

Tags: java, rhino, nashorn, scriptengine

ScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName looks up and creates a ScriptEngine for a given name.

Rhino registers itself as "js", "rhino", "JavaScript", "javascript", "ECMAScript", and "ecmascript"

Nashorn registers itself as "nashorn", "Nashorn", "js", "JS", "JavaScript", "javascript", "ECMAScript", and "ecmascript"

If I use a name like "js" which both Nashorn and Rhino have registered with, which script engine will be used? Will it use Nashorn on Java 8 and Rhino otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html#registerEngineName-java.lang.String-javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory-) for `registerEngineName`:

> Registers a ScriptEngineFactory to handle a language name. Overrides
>   any such association found using the Discovery mechanism.

And also at the `registerEngineName` source code (note that `nameAssociations` is a hash map):

```
public void registerEngineName(String name, ScriptEngineFactory factory) {
    if (name == null || factory == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        nameAssociations.put(name, factory);
}
```

So, it seems that, for a given name, `getEngineByName` will return the script engine factory that was the last to be registered for that name.

As script engine factories are loaded through the [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) mechanism, the loading order will depend on the order that the service configuration files are enumerated by the relevant class loaders' [`getResources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResources-java.lang.String-) method.

For a default installation, all this does not matter too much as Java 8 only includes Nashorn, and Java 7 and earlier only include Rhino. If you would add an additional engine through the system class path, it will be loaded after the one loaded by the bootstrap/extension class loader, and thus take precedence.

Comment: This isn't quite right, because the discovery mechanism doesn't use `registerEngineName` at all.  If no names were registered explicitly, you actually get the first matching engine which pops out of a `HashSet`.  

It's more random than classloader order, because it comes down to `java.lang.Object.hashCode`, and varies from one run to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code, `registerEngineName` is indeed deterministic, however the discovery mechanism is a separate thing (as implied by the JavaDoc), and it is non-deterministic, because it adds all the engines to a `HashSet` during discovery, and when asked for an engine by name, it just uses the first match it finds.

You can run into this if you install [an updated Rhino `ScriptEngine`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872885/14379) in Java 7 and request it by any of the usual names (`js`, `rhino`, etc).

But unless you do that, both Java 7 and Java 8 come with exactly one implementation, which answers to `js`, `javascript`, `ecmascript`, etc.  As long as you don't ask for `rhino` or `nashorn`, it should work in both cases.