# How can I specify exact rhino implementation instead of that embedded to JDK?

Tags: java, rhino, javax.script

I use rhino script in my application.
I found that on different environments it works different.
For example, on open-jdk this code doesn't work

```
eval("JSON.stringify({id:1})")
```

whereas on Oracle's JDK works.

This is obviously because each JDK contains it's own implementation of Rhino.

I added the following to dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
    <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
    <version>1.7R4</version>
</dependency>
```

How can I specify to use this implementation ?

**Update**: I call rhino not directly but through javax.script API

```
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval("JSON.stringify({})")
```

Comment: what is a "simple JDK"?

Comment: JDK that was downloaded from Oracle site. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: ah, so Oracle JDK. so are you looking into packaging the rhino implementation together with your application? have you been looking some posts about it, like [this one](http://www.ivanparraga.com/2014/03/16/embedding-mozilla-rhino-and-pass-java-objects-to-javascript/)? what is your exact issue if you try to follow it?

Comment: Perhaps you are talking about different -versions- of Rhino? Rhino IS the 'implementation', there is only one. But there are different versions of course and perhaps the available Javascript APIs are different in each version, sure. The JDK readme actually explains exactly how this has been dealt with for you: https://jdk7.java.net/rhino/README.TXT . Just in case of link-rot: The packages of the bundled Rhino have been changed, so you can use a later version simply by using the proper original Rhino packages.

Comment: I see what is confusing. I try to call rhino not directly but through javax.script API.

Comment: That's why I cannot just change the rhino package.

Comment: **getEngineFactories()** - Adding the jar on the class path with a script engine will add the script engine via the Java SPI (Service Provider Interface). So simply enumerate all script engines and see which is the desired JavaScript/ECMAScript one. The implementing class name of the script engine's interface should give sufficient identification.

Answer (score 0):

You need an implementation of `javax.script.ScriptEngine` which uses which uses the package `org.mozilla.javascript`, rather than the JDK's implementation, which uses the repackaged `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal`.

[de.christophkraemer:rhino-script-engine](https://github.com/cevou/rhino-script-engine) is such an implementation, borrowed from the OpenJDK source.  More [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28872885/14379).